# Xubuntu 18.04 daily front left and right left channels are not balanced in PulseAudio

Tags: sound, xubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

[image: Example]

Quite often, at least daily the right and left channel for my analog output are not balanced. I have to set it to 0 to rebalance them perfectly, then increase volume to desired range.

I am using `amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%+` to increase volume and `amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%-` to decrease the volume as keyboard shortcuts for the "volume up/down" hotkeys on keyboard.

Any idea why the balance is always off after I reset it, from just using those 2 commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've found the solution.

I had 4 shortcuts in the keyboard "Application Shortcuts" menu. volume-up for media+ key, and ctrl+pageup key. Also volume-down for media- key, and ctrl+pagedown key.

I removed the "ctrl" variants of the shortcuts, and so far no left/right unbalance has happened.

Will update if anything changes.